# Need help trying to make site bigger via CSS. I've included examples

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a larger site (that is responsive) like goo.gl/FnBGO ... I am running the same theme at goo.gl/c9zLP - It looks like there side bar image is 370 wide and will go to 300 and small as you resize the browser. Also I"m not sure if it is the padding, or something else that is making my current side bar image display at even less than 300 width (which is what it should be.) Looking forward to any feedback / suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using a child theme and media queries. See wordpress codex on child themes and twitter bootstraps website for more info on how this is done.